# Gradle :: runtime.exclude group: 'org.apache.hadoop' affects test scope?

Tags: gradle, shadowjar

I have the following in my build.gradle:

```
configurations {
  runtime.exclude group: 'org.apache.spark'
  runtime.exclude group: 'org.apache.hadoop'
}
```

and for some reason this also excludes all Hadoop/Spark code from the test classpath. If I comment out this configuration - the tests are passing fine, otherwise I get all sorts of `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/MiniDFSCluster$Builder` issues.

I tried to use this:

```
test {
  classpath += configurations.compile
```

}

No luck.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gradle scoping, `test` inherits from `runtime`.  Your test code is excluding the minicluster dependency because runtime excludes it.

See this diagram for the scope inheritance tree for the java plugin:
[image: gradle configuration inheritance]

Instead of adding a global exclude to the runtime configuration, you might want to make the spark dependencies into `compileOnly` scoped dependencies which is available since gradle 2.12.

```
configurations {
  compileOnly 'org.apache.spark:spark:2.11'
  test 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-minicluster:2.7.2'
}
```

More information about gradle scoping is available in the [gradle manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management):

Alternatively, you could add another configuration that inherits from runtime, and add exclusions to that, then use that as the basis of your shadowJar.  This could be helpful if you want to optionally build a jar with spark dependencies bundled in or not.  Your tests will use the configuration without exclusions, but the jar you package won't include the spark dependencies.

```
configurations {
    sparkConfiguration {
        extendsFrom runtime
        exclude group: 'org.apache.hadoop'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.spark'
    }
}

task sparkExcludedJar(type: ShadowJar) {
    group = "Shadow"
    configurations = [project.configurations.sparkConfiguration]
    classifier = 'sparkExcluded'
}
```

Comment: I've ended up with doing something like that - added another configuration reference with the exclusion of those hadoop/spark groups and transitive deps, and used that config in the `shadowJar` plugin execution. Many thanks for the diagram and the explanation!